# Get the Best Combination of sharing Blocks

Tags: c#, algorithm

i have Problem to Solve, if can anyone helps me.
the Problem is:
i have 30 Blocks, each Block has deferent area
for example:

```
Block  1 :   517 m2
       2 :    50 m2
       3 :   430 m2
       .
       .
       .
      30 :   380 m2
    ---------------
     sum   84720 m2
```

5 People want to share this Blocks so every one should have 84720 m2 / 5 =  around 16944 m2
so what is the best Algorithm in C# that will make the best combination of the Blocks, that each one will have blocks around 16944 m2.
I hope it is clear.
thx in advanced

Comment: You should define *penalty function* to compare different solution: e.g. what's better: 3 people have *exactly* 16944 m2 and two `13944` and `19944` or `15944, 17944, 15944, 16944, 17944`

Comment: This type of problem is called a PACKING Problem.  Mathematicians have been trying to solve this issue for 2000 years and have not found an algorithm.